# Calculating the solubility for chromium(III) hydroxide using the complex ion constant

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, equilibrium, aqueous-solution

#### Problem

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{Cr(OH)3(s) &<=> Cr^3+(aq) + 3 OH-(aq)} &\quad K_\mathrm{sp} &= \pu{6.7E-31} \\
> \ce{Cr^3+(aq) + 4 OH-(aq) &<=> Cr(OH)4-(aq)} &\quad K_\mathrm{f} &= \pu{8E29}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> The solubility of $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ in pure water is $\pu{1.3E-8 M}.$
> The solubility of $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ in $\pu{0.50 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ when the complex ion $\ce{Cr(OH)4-}$ is formed is:
>
> a) $\pu{0.32 M}$
> b) $\pu{0.59 M}$
> c) $\pu{0.27 M}$
> d) $\pu{0.18 M}$

#### Answer

> d) $\pu{0.18 M}$

#### My approach

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3(s) + OH-(aq) <=> Cr(OH)4-(aq)} \quad K = K_\mathrm{sp}\cdot K_\mathrm{f}$$

$$\pu{6.7E-31}\times\pu{8E29} = \frac{s}{\pu{0.50 M}}$$

$$s = \pu{0.27 M}$$

As you can see I got c), which is not the correct answer. Could anyone point out what I did wrong?